# Various Errors within Code

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm currently writing a program as part of a weekly assignment, and I've hit a wall. That may be obvious to some but has stumped me.

My problem is that the compiler is returning these errors: [image: Error Messages]

I've played around with the code a bit to try and correct myself, but that runs me into other errors. I'm not quite sure as to why the `INTENT(IN)` definitions at the top are coming back to me as 'not a DUMMY' variable.

As well as have no idea, how to correct the actual argument error below. I've tried to use my variables `Dial_A_In` and `Dial_A_Out` etc. to return a logical value to check a combination, but to no avail.

Here is my code: [image: My Code]

Errors and Relevant Code in Text Form:

```
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: Dial_A_In , Dial_B_In , Dial_C_In
```

Returns Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable.

```
IF (check_solution() .EQV. .TRUE.) EXIT
```

Returns Error: Missing actual argument for argument 'a' at (1)

EDIT: I've managed to fix the call for check_solution(), it was a three integer argument string, which can be seen below.

Full code as Text:

```
SUBROUTINE sevensub(Dial_A_Out, Dial_B_Out, Dial_C_Out, Iteration_Count)

USE globals_mod


INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: Dial_A_In , Dial_B_In , Dial_C_In
INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: Dial_A_Out , Dial_B_Out , Dial_C_Out , Iteration_Count

Iteration_Count = 0

DO Dial_A_Out = 1, Dial_A_In, 1

    DO Dial_B_Out = 1, Dial_B_In, 1

        DO Dial_C_Out = 1, Dial_C_In, 1

        WRITE(*,*) '1st Dial:', Dial_A_Out, '2nd Dial:', Dial_B_Out, '3rd Dial:', Dial_C_Out, 'Number of Iterations:', Iteration_Count

        Iteration_Count = Iteration_Count + 1

        IF (check_solution(Dial_A_Out, Dial_B_Out, Dial_C_Out) .EQV. .TRUE.) EXIT

        END DO

    IF (check_solution(Dial_A_Out, Dial_B_Out, Dial_C_Out) .EQV. .TRUE.) EXIT

    END DO

IF (check_solution(Dial_A_Out, Dial_B_Out, Dial_C_Out) .EQV. .TRUE.) EXIT

END DO

IF (check_solution(Dial_A_Out, Dial_B_Out, Dial_C_Out) .EQV. .TRUE.) THEN

    WRITE(*,*) 'The Combination has been Found'
    WRITE(*,*) 'It took', Iteration_Count, 'attempts'

ELSE IF (check_solution(Dial_A_Out, Dial_B_Out, Dial_C_Out) .EQV. .FALSE.) THEN

    WRITE(*,*) 'The Combination could not be Found'

END IF

END SUBROUTINE sevensub
```

Problem is I cannot open the source file of the module and see what it is calling for, so it's kind of a guessing game.

Comment: Post the relevant code and errors here directly, as text.

Comment: INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: Dial_A_In , Dial_B_In , Dial_C_In  

Returns Error: Symbol at (1) is not a DUMMY variable.

IF (check_solution() .EQV. .TRUE.) EXIT

Returns Error: Missing actual argument for argument 'a' at (1)

Problem is I cannot open the source file of the MODULE and see what it is calling for, so it's kind of a guessing game.

Comment: Not in a comment as a jumbled mess. Instead, [edit] your post and put it there, where it can be properly formatted and easily seen.

Comment: I've included the images in the question, but please add them as plain text instead.  In terms of the errors about `check_solution` you'll need to determine the correct way of calling that function.  For the complaints about dummy variables: well, `dial_a_in` etc., aren't dummy variables so they can't have an `intent` attribute.  We'll need to know what level of understanding you have to be able to appropriately express an answer.

Comment: I've managed to figure out the check_solution() function, as it was calling for a three variable argument to be used. I've used the values for Dial_A-C_Out as this, as this is the variable to be checked against that which is stored in the MODULE file. 

I'm in Week 7 of this course at the moment, but it's the first time I have come across SUBROUTINES and ARG strings in Fortran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the keyword `INTENT` into a variable declaration means that it is a dummy variable.

But this dummy variable is not in the list of parameters for the subroutine.

What you want is probably:

```
subroutine sevensub(Dial_A_In, Dial_A_Out, Dial_B_In, Dial_B_Out, &
                    Dial_C_In, Dial_C_Out, Iteration_Count)
    use ...
    integer, intent(in) : Dial_A_In, Dial_B_In, Dial_C_In
    integer, intent(out): Dial_A_Out, Dial_B_Out, Dial_C_Out
    integer, intent(out): Iteration_Count

    ...

end subroutine sevensub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just refreshed the SO page and you've confirmed exactly what I have just written.

Couldn't wrap my head around why it was throwing me errors, but I added it into the top part of the SUBROUTINE and it hasn't thrown anything back yet.

Once again thank you